# Can I upload an Android apk developed with Android SDK to the Amazon App Store?

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

have you any idea?
I want to developed app in google android sdk. which app i want to upload in amazon app store.

Please suggest me.

THANK YOU...

Comment: You can upload to amazon store..

Comment: For amazone store not any configuration chanage in menifest file?

Comment: same configurations as like tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon devices are largely Android compatible (they say "75% of apps just work"). The biggest challenge comes if you are using Google specific services (such as Maps, Cloud Messaging, Purchasing etc) as they are not supported though there are Amazon specific alternatives that you can use.

You can get a quick (automated) evaluation of your app on their "[Test your app](https://developer.amazon.com/tya/welcome.html)" page to help quantify the work (if any) you will need to do.